# How to display cart and account links on blog pages in magento?

Tags: wordpress, magento, integration

I have integrated fishpig wordpress blog integrated with magento and integrated theme

but I need to display `my cart, my account, login, blog` in header in blog pages

so what could I write in `header.php` file in blog

please help me out

thanks and hope for answer

Comment: What is the integration mode? (full, etc?), header links are displayed via xml (if you use that section in your layout)... By default your these links are displayed in Magento theme header...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the pages' handle in the layout XML.

Then just add the block top.links.

If you need help with layout XML see [a here](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates)

Pesach

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want that in wordpress blog pages, in that how can i do that?

Comment: oh this should answer your question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347384/load-block-outside-magento-and-apply-current-template