# Magento and Drupal sessions conflicts -- how to resolve?

Tags: api, magento, session, drupal

I'm trying to write a block that loads the Magento shopping cart inside of a Drupal block.

The following code (located in /test.php) loads the shopping cart and its contents properly (Magento install located in /magento):

```
<?php
      /*
       * Initialize magento.
       */
      require_once('magento/app/Mage.php');
      umask(0);
      Mage::app('default');
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
      Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
      /*
       * Add specific layout handles to our layout and then load them.
       */
      $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
      $layout->getUpdate()
          ->addHandle('default')
          ->load();

      /*
       * Generate blocks, but XML from previously loaded layout handles must be
       * loaded first.
       */
      $layout->generateXml()
             ->generateBlocks();

      /* 
       * Now we can simply get any block in the usual way.
       */
      $cart = $layout->getBlock('cart_sidebar')->toHtml();
      echo $cart;
?>
```

(I'm using FirePHP to debug session values -- that's what the fb(); calls are for.)

If I use that exact same code within Drupal (via a hook_menu callback), I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract::getMessages(): The
>   script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete
>   object. Please ensure that the class definition
>   "Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection" of the object you are
>   trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or
>   provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in
>   /home/aendrew/workspace/drupgento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php
>   on line 215

My guess is that Drupal's doing some sort of session handling that's conflicting with Magento's -- if I unset $_SESSION at the start of the script, it displays an empty cart (regardless of whether or not there are actually items in it). I've also tried putting the existing session in a temporary variable and then doing an array_merge() at the end, but that doesn't work either.

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Try to start from here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cart#methods

Comment: @Zyava I've gone through that already. Method `cart.info` requires integer `quoteId`, which is the ID of an existing shopping cart. I could avoid all this if I had the `quoteId`, but I don't know how to get it for the current user (And especially outside of a Magento session) -- this is really what I'm asking in Point #2.

Comment: Worth adding that I have my cookie path set to "/" in `admin->system->configuration->web.`

Comment: Have you tried to load the magento part with ajax instead? So that the two frameworks are never running for the same request.

Comment: @regilero -- That's kind of been my fall-back idea, but it's not nearly as optimized as simply loading the Magento app via PHP (It would essentially double the load on Apache) -- plus it requires the user to have JavaScript enabled. Sylvain's solution below is working great, I'll post how I modified his JFusion plugin class for Drupal later on today.

Comment: @aendrew I am facing the same problem, would not able to resolve. Can you please share your drupal code where you made changes to destroy session and then again start session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked on an integration between Joomla and MAgento I get the same problem. 
The solution I provide is maybe not the best solution but it was the only one I found to share sessions between a single PHP script process.

I had to "stop" the Joomla session, do my stuff with Magento and start again the session in Joomla all of it during the same script process. Here is a sample of what I did for a Joomla plugin, you can get an inspiration of that because I'm not aware of Drupal Framework but here you will find the code I did for the Joomla plugin: http://pastie.org/5505841#4

The most interesting part in the code provided are the methods `destroyTemporaryJoomlaSession`, `loadAndStartMagentoBootstrap`, `restartJoomlaSession`, `startMagentoSession` and `stopMagentoSession`.

Then I use this plugin in some Joomla module in this way:

```
$plgMageLib = new plgSystemMagelib ( );
$plgMageLib->destroyTemporaryJoomlaSession ();
if ($plgMageLib->loadAndStartMagentoBootstrap ()) :
    $plgMageLib->startMagentoSession ();

    /* Content of Magento logic, blocks or else */

    $html = '';
    $blockId = $params->get ( 'block_id', '' );
    echo JFusion_Helper_Mageselectblock::callblock ( $blockId );

    /* EOF */

    $plgMageLib->stopMagentoSession ();

endif;
$plgMageLib->restartJoomlaSession ();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome. I'll take a look at that in a few minutes -- working on this today. Thanks!

Comment: ER. MAH. GERRRRRD! I totally have it working! I've been floundering at this for *days*! I'll test it out a bit more and mark this as the answer -- thank you so much!

Comment: Really happy that it works because I have worked hard on it to provide it for the Jfusion Project. I didn't know if it could work for Drupal.

Comment: JFusion is rad, I used it a few years ago for a few projects -- good to hear people are still doing cool stuff with it!

Comment: @aendrew: i am stuck with the same problem. can you post me how to achieve it?

Comment: @zamil -- I'm not sure my employer would appreciate it (That said, I'm trying to convince it to open source what we come up with). However, it's really not hard once you look at Sylvain's code. Strip out all the Joomla!-specific functions, replace them with their Drupal equivalents and it pretty much works.

Comment: @aendrew: as suggested in the answer i destroyed the session before i load mage object to drupal.But it still returns nothing

Comment: Have you done the change with the autoload module? You need to comment out a function in Magento and then force its autoload via `spl_autoload_register ( '__autoload' ); Varien_Autoload::register ();`

Answer (score 0):

Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start();