# Blocks available in Magento

Tags: wordpress, magento, block

I'm trying to access magento from wordpress. Here below is the simple code I used to access magento sidebar cart.

```
<?php

/*
 * Initialize magento.
 */
require_once '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/conover-store/app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();

/*
 * Add specific layout handles to our layout and then load them.
 */
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()
    ->addHandle('default')
    ->addHandle('some_other_handle')
    ->load();

/*
 * Generate blocks, but XML from previously loaded layout handles must be
 * loaded first.
 */
$layout->generateXml()
       ->generateBlocks();

/* 
 * Now we can simply get any block in the usual way.
 */
$cart = $layout->getBlock('header')->toHtml();
echo $cart;

?>
```

I'm looking for a full list/documentation of available block codes like "cart_sidebar", "header", etc.,

Comment: This should solve this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347384/load-block-outside-magento-and-apply-current-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there is no full list, as they are all arbitrary!

Every `<block name="..." />` declaration from layout XML *may* or *may not* be available for a rendering scope. Rendering scope is determined by the layout update handles which are set for the update object when `load()` is called. Additionally, blocks can be instantiated directly in PHP by the layout object.

So, for a particular rendering scope, there are many options. When all that is needed is a particular block and its children, it's up to the developer to determine if it's worth instantiating all of the blocks for a rendering scope. For the current question, it seems that this is the case. So all of the available blocks can be determined by inspecting the layout object's protected `_blocks` property:

```
// after generateBlocks() is called...

$blocks = $layout->getAllBlocks();
sort($blocks);

$list = "<table><thead><tr><th>Name in Layout</th><th>Class</th><th>Template</th></tr></thead>";
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $list .= sprintf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',$block->getNameInLayout(),get_class($block),$block->getTemplateFile());
}
$list .= "</table>";

echo $list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the current path to access **Mage.php** file.

For example,

Wordpress is under **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/**
And Magento is under **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/**

Use the below code to include Mage file from a file under wordpress root.

```
require_once '../magento/app/Mage.php';
```