# Including magento header outside of magento. Problems with $this->getChildHtml()

Tags: magento

I have researched this topic pretty thoroughly but can't find an answer.

I am trying to include a Magneto head into a WordPress page. I created a new wordpress template and added the following code to it.

```
try {
    require_once ABSPATH . '/app/Mage.php';

    if (Mage::isInstalled()) {
        $mage = Mage::app();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

        if(Mage::getDesign()->designPackageExists('xxx')) {
            Mage::getDesign()->setPackageName('xxx');
            Mage::getDesign()->setTheme('xxx');             
        }


        // init translator
        $mage->getTranslator()->init('frontend');

        // init head
        $head = $mage->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('page/html_head');        
} }
```

Then a bit further down in the template I have

```
echo $head->toHtml();
```

Now what is happening is some parts of the head are being echoed and some parts are not.

When I go into head.phtml and try to figure out what is happening I notice that any line that contains

```
$this->getChildHtml()
```

does not get echoed.

I looked at [this example](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/using-magento-header-footer-outside-of-magento/) and noticed that the author is manually adding the html and CSS. Why is this? Why don't they get added automatically? Is this a related problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a block that is generated inside the header block, you need to first create it, then set it as child of the header block.

eg. Here is how I display within Wordpress a Magento header block, including the currency drop-down block that was generated by getChildHtml() inside the original header.phtml:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

$headerBlock = $layout->createBlock('page/html_header')->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml');
$currencyBlock = $layout->createBlock('directory/currency')->setTemplate('currency/currency.phtml');
$headerBlock->setChild('currency_selector', $currencyBlock);
$headerBlock = $headerBlock->toHtml();
```

Then you can write the block where you need it on the page:

```
echo $headerBlock;
```

I know it's a little late but hopefully this helps others with this issue.

Comment: I want to load my current theme header how can we load.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with how magento layouts are rendered? With `$head = $mage->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('page/html_head');` you create a new block without any children. That's why  the author needs to add JS and CSS again. To load the default head block have a look at this thread [Load block outside Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347384/load-block-outside-magento-and-apply-current-template). You can load it with `$layout->getBlock('head')->toHtml();`.