# Including magento header outside scope of magento & remove prototype

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, magento-1.7

I'd like to include my magento header in a wordpress blog.  I've accomplished this (in a similar manner to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952974/including-magento-header-outside-of-magento-problems-with-this-getchildhtml) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347384/load-block-outside-magento-and-apply-current-template), but I don't need a lot of the libraries loaded by Magento in the header (eg.  prototype, scriptaculous etc.)

I'm a little stuck at this stage.  How do I remove these libraries from `$layout` before rendering it to html?

Here's my code so far...

```
<?php

$layout = Mage::app('default')->setCurrentStore( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )->getLayout();
global $layout;
if(class_exists('Mage')){
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
}
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$login_status = '';
if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    $login_status = 'customer_logged_in';
} else {
    $login_status = 'customer_logged_out';
}

$layout = Mage::app('default')->setCurrentStore( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
    ->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()
    ->addHandle('default')
    ->addHandle('wordpress')
    ->addHandle($login_status)
    ->load();

$layout->generateXml()
    ->generateBlocks();

?>
<html>
<head>
<!-- .... some things .... -->
<?php
    wp_head();
    echo $layout->getBlock('head')->toHtml(); 
?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

ahh... got it

```
$layout->getBlock('head')->removeItem('js','prototype/prototype.js');
```

etc...